# Override class from CSS module in NextJS

Tags: css, next.js, module, antd

I am attempting to override the default behavior of ant-design's Calendar component, by making it stop highlighting today's date. The class in question is the one selected in the inspector in this image:

[image: Image of ant-design calendar with class that highlights today]

As you can see the border 1px solid #1677ff creates this blue border around the date (13/06/2023 today).

If I add this to my `globals.css` file it overrides the class correctly, removing the highlighted border:

```
.ant-picker-calendar .ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-today .ant-picker-cell-inner::before {
    border: unset;
}
```

While this works, I DON'T want to globally add this style, so I tried adding the styling to the CSS module of the component where I use the calendar instead.

Component.tsx:

```
import styles from './Component.module.css';
<Calendar
    fullscreen={false}
    className={styles.todayNoHighlight}
/>
```

Component.module.css:

```
.todayNoHighlight .ant-picker-calendar .ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-today .ant-picker-cell-inner::before {
    border: unset !important;
}
.todayNoHighlight {
    background-color: #3A7734;
}
```

The green background color, which you can also see in the image above, is only added as reference to show that the class is imported and applied correctly.

The issue is that `border: unset` does not get applied. It does not even get overridden. It just isn't there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried removing .todayNoHighlight class selector and just using .ant-picker-calendar .ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-today .ant-picker-cell-inner::before in your Component.module.css file?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes I have and simply nothing happens. When inspecting the style is not applied.